# Smallest positive integer n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The smallest positive integer $n$ with $24$ divisors (where $1$ and $n$ are also considered as divisors of $n$) is?

As far as I know it can be solved like this:
prime factors of $24$ are : $(2,2,2,3)$
So, the smallest number will be $a^1 \times b^1 \times c^1 \times d^2$.
where $a=7$, $b=5$, $c=3$ and $d=2$.
I got the exponents of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ by subtracting $1$ from the prime factors of $24$.

This way I am getting the answer as $420$ but the answer is $360$.

Now I need help as to if I am not doing the question correctly or I am skipping some bit of information (I think $1$ and $n$ being inclusive in divisors is something that is giving me the wrong answer).

Please help me.....!

Comment: Since you already know the correct answer, you should tray factorizing $360$ first. Can you see where does your reasoning fail?

Comment: No yet i'm not able to understand!

Comment: $2^{23} $ will have 24 factors as 24=24 as well as 2.2.2.3.  Why do you think you have break 24 down to its *prime* factors.  24 = 6.8 so $3^52^7$ also has 24 factors. If $5^2*3*2^2 < 7*5*3*2^2$ (which it is) you certainly do *not* want to break it into prime factors.

Comment: 24 is not equal to 6.8.........its equal to 48.........what are u trying to say?

Comment: Gosh darn it!  I meant 24 = 3.8 so $3^22^7$ also has 24 factors.  My point being that you *don't* want to break 24 to its prime factors necessarily.

Comment: oh now i get your point! Thank you so much.......i appreciate it! @fleablood

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of numbers having exactly $24$ factors because if $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha2}....p_k^{\alpha_k}$ then the total number of factors of $n$ is equal to $(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)....(\alpha_k+1)$

You try with $n=2^a3^b5^c$ and $$(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=24$$

The number $24=2^3\cdot3$ has $(3+1)(1+1)=8$ factors and some easy calculation gives $$a+1=4\\b+1=3\\c+1=2$$ Thus $$\color{red}{n=2^33^25=360}$$

Comment: Woah that was easy........thanks  a lot!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a prime factorisation of 24. Other factorisations may also work.

So $24=4 \times 3 \times 2$

So a candidate is $a^3 \times b^2 \times c^1$

$24$ can be factored in many ways, each giving a corresponding number that has $24$ divisors:

$24=24 \Rightarrow 2^{23}$ has 24 divisors.

$24=12 \times 2 \Rightarrow 2^{11} \times 3^1$ has 24 divisors.

$24=8 \times 3 \Rightarrow 2^{7} \times 3^2$ has 24 divisors.

$24=6 \times 4 \Rightarrow 2^{5} \times 3^3$ has 24 divisors.

$24=4 \times 3 \times 2 \Rightarrow 2^{3} \times 3^2 \times 5^1$ has 24 divisors.

$24=6 \times 2 \times 2 \Rightarrow 2^{5} \times 3^1 \times 5^1$ has 24 divisors.

$24=3 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \Rightarrow 2^{2} \times 3^1 \times 5^1 \times 7^1$ has 24 divisors.

Then, we find out which is the minimum. Hope this helped!!!!! :D

Comment: But why is the prime factorisation not working?It works in other cases.........like if we do for 60 divisors.I don't understand that if 1 and the number itself are included as divisors ,then will it change the process somehow?

Comment: Because $2^3 \times 3^2 \times 5^1 <2^2 \times 3^1 \times 5^1 \times 7^1$ which is ultimately because $2^1 \times 3^1 < 7^1$.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the fact that $1$ and $n$ are included as divisors.

Comment: Oh i got it! Thank you so much........ and I am obliged for the editing! @tomi

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

$N=2^a \cdot3^b \cdot5^c$.
We can write
\begin{align} 24 &= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \\ (a+1)(b+1)(c+1) &= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4. \end{align}
$C$ takes the smallest value.
\begin{align}
c+1=2; \quad c&=1 \\
b+1=3; \quad b&=2 \\
a+1=4; \quad a&=3 \\
N=2^3 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1 &=360.
\end{align}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).